# What is the significance of Mark 14:51?

Tags: mark

Mark 14:51

> <sup>**51**</sup> Now a certain young man followed Him, having a linen cloth thrown around his naked body. And the young men laid hold of him, <sup>**52**</sup> and he left the linen cloth and fled from them naked.

This bit of text above is inserted between the betrayal in the Garden and the prosecution of Jesus. It seems random, what is its significance?